# How exactly class weights intervene in the backpropagation equations of a neural network?

Tags: python, math, neural-network, loss-function, backpropagation

I'm implementing a classification neural network from scratch (no libraries except numpy). I am following this tutorial : http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html . However, I am dealing with an unbalanced dataset. Thus I compute a *class weight* for each category/class of the dataset. I compute the class weight *w_i* of the *i*-th category with the formula (got from this article : https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/10/improve-class-imbalance-class-weights/ ) :

```
w_i = n / (N * n_i)
```

where :

- *n* is the total number of samples in the dataset;
- *n_i* is the number of samples of category *i*
- *N* is the number of categories

**Now that I have these class weights, how do they intervene in the backpropagation algorithm ? Where exactly must I use these *w_i* coefficients in the backpropagation formulas and how ?**

My first idea (that I got from this article : https://peltarion.com/knowledge-center/documentation/modeling-view/build-an-ai-model/class-weights ) is that the loss and the error simply get multiplied by the class weight of the category that was expected for this sample :

```py
# y : expected output of the network
# activations : array of outputs at each layer, thus activations[-1]
#               is the output of the network
# zs : inputs of each layer (i.e. the input vector at a layer before
#      it goes through the activation function)

# y and activations[-1] are of shape : (number of categories, 1)

# Get the class weight of the expected category
class_id = np.argmax(y)
cw = class_weights[class_id]

# Loss (only used for metrics) : Mean Squared Error (MSE)
loss = 1 / y.shape[0] * np.sum((y - activations[-1]) ** 2)
# Apply class weight on the loss
loss *= cw

# (simplified) MSE cost derivative (error)
# Applying the class weight to the error
error = (activations[-1] - y) * self.dactivation(zs[-1])
# Applying the class weight to the error
error *= cw

# Gradients of the last layer
w_grads[-1] = np.matmul(error, activations[-2].transpose())
b_grads[-1] = error
```

However, this results in a very slow training, here is an extract of the training logs :

```
Epoch 0: 0.0% (0 / 21892) | loss : 0.1675
Epoch 1: 0.0% (4 / 21892) | loss : 0.1578
Epoch 2: 0.0% (1 / 21892) | loss : 0.1521
Epoch 3: 0.4% (88 / 21892) | loss : 0.1460
Epoch 4: 4.8% (1045 / 21892) | loss : 0.1352
Epoch 5: 6.9% (1514 / 21892) | loss : 0.1230
Epoch 6: 7.9% (1726 / 21892) | loss : 0.1134
Epoch 7: 7.9% (1740 / 21892) | loss : 0.1060
Epoch 8: 8.3% (1807 / 21892) | loss : 0.1006
Epoch 9: 8.6% (1893 / 21892) | loss : 0.0963
Epoch 10: 9.5% (2076 / 21892) | loss : 0.0927
Epoch 11: 10.2% (2228 / 21892) | loss : 0.0894
Epoch 12: 12.9% (2829 / 21892) | loss : 0.0865
Epoch 13: 15.9% (3470 / 21892) | loss : 0.0838
Epoch 14: 18.8% (4109 / 21892) | loss : 0.0815
Epoch 15: 26.0% (5701 / 21892) | loss : 0.0795
```

The accuracy is calculated on a test dataset, and is at **0 %** after the first epoch (shouldn't it be at around 50% ?) and then very slowly increases. The batch size is 200 samples. Training a Keras model with the same layers, activation functions, loss and class weights on the same dataset is way faster and more efficient (reaching up to 92% accuracy after 30 epochs).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you should look at Boosting algorithms, to be precise ADA boost if your goal is to incorporate weights. However note that boosting is usually used with a weak classifier/regressor (model).... The link you supplied is almost the same as ADA boost minus the descent steps.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, what is missing in my implementations is that the class weights shouldn't be constant but change at each epoch/batch ? Is it how Keras implements class weights ? (when using the `class_weights` argument : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras)